# Scale the Skin Modifier on a Specific Axis

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow, axis

I'm trying to learn how to use the skin modifier effectively, and realized that it would be beneficial to understand how to scale the modifier on specific axis, instead of in general, without having to select the radius properties in the N menu. I know that it can be done, based on what I've seen in videos floating around, but I don't quite understand *how* to do so.

Ive tried doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>Y</kbd>) but neither of those had any affect

How do I scale the skin modifier on a specific axis with hotkeys?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, when I try so scale on only Y for example, it scales on the Y and the Z. I think it has something to do with how the skin modifier works, because I cannot manually scale on Z axis at all. Could be similar to how you can't scale a flat plane on the Z. I could be wrong, though, I will upvote in case someone who knows more has a better answer.

Comment: What version are you using? In 2.91 pressing x/y works for me.

Comment: @HISEROD

Im using version 2.91, when i press x, it deletes the vertice or worse, and when I press y, nothing happens

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant pressing Ctrl A then (before confirming) pressing x or y.               
                                                                                                                                 
Btw Blender displays the options at the bottom of the window. (but only the X,Y,Shft,Ctrl keys should be visible for this particular tool. Probably a bug.)

Comment: @HISEROD before confirming? I never get the choice to confirm or not, i thought it just automatically scaled, it never brings up a menu or anything for me to confirm

Comment: The left click is the confirmation.

Comment: What left click? I never get the choice, i just press ctrl a and then the effect takes place

Comment: @HISEROD
Sorry I see what you mean now. That actually works perfectly, my issue is that I was pressing ctrl+a+x all at the same time, not pressing ctrl+a and then pressing x. Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Hiserod in the comments was able to help me

My issue is that I was pressing ctrl+a+x all at the same time, not pressing ctrl+a and then pressing x/y/z separately from that.